# Is it possible to combine two audio sources from my PC into one audio source?

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, combine

I would like to combine an audio source (like stereo mix) and my microphone into one single audio source which can then be used as a microphone is a program such as Skype. So in essence I would like the sound from my computer and the sound from my microphone to both go through Skype so the person on the other end of the call can hear both.

Is there any piece of software which will allow me to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) or [VoiceMeeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/)

Comment: Or this free, donation supported Virtual Audio Cable from the same guy who made VoiceMeeter http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm